# Draw phase diagram of $x''+\sin x=0$ around $(0,0)$ manually

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am going to draw the phase digram of $x''(t)+\sin(x(t))=0$ around point $o=(0,0)$ manually .

My ideas so far:
Let $y=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Then :
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-\sin x
\end{align}$$
If I use first order approximation, then I have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-x
\end{equation}
This coefficient matrix  of this equation set is: \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
and it's eigenvalue is $i,-i$. So, the null solution of the approximation equation set is a center point. But the null solution of the orgin equation set can be center point or focus point. How can I distinguish them?

P.S., by appling Lyapunov function $V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}y^2+1-\cos x$ to the orign equation set, I know $(0,0)$ is stable. Also, by coding from wolframalpha, I know $(0,0)$ is a center point, but I would like to know how to prove it.

Comment: The linearization doesn't tell you the forward in time stability when the largest real part of any eigenvalue is zero. (Same with backward in time stability when the smallest one is zero).

Comment: But as you mentioned, you can look at $V=y^2/2+1-\cos(x)$ so that $\frac{dV}{dt}=0$. Then just examine connected components of $\{ (x,y) : V(x,y)=V_0 \}$ where $0<V_0 \ll 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Do you mean that since $\frac{dV}{dt}=0$, then $(0,0)$ is stable? So $(0,0)$ is a center point?@lan

Comment: That by itself doesn't imply stability, it just implies the dynamics move around on a level set of $V$. You then need to show that connected components of level sets of $V$, with $V_0$ close enough to $V(0,0)$, are confined to a small neighborhood of $(0,0)$. But this is not so complicated; to have $V=\epsilon$, you must have $|y| \leq \sqrt{2\epsilon}$ and $|x| \leq \cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks your your response. You are right that if we have $V=\epsilon$, we must have $|y|\leq \sqrt{2 \epsilon}$ and $|x|\leq cos^{-1}(1- \epsilon)$. But what can we derive next?@lan

Comment: Now you need to show that for any $\delta>0$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the connected component of $\{ (x,y) : |y| \leq \sqrt{2\epsilon},1-\cos(x) \leq \epsilon \}$ which contains $(0,0)$ is contained inside $B_\delta((0,0))$. This implies that if you start in $\{ V=\epsilon \}$ then you stay in $B_\delta((0,0))$. Finally to finish you need continuity of $V$ (which ensures that $V$ can be made small by starting close to $(0,0)$).

Comment: This is the way to proof the stability of $(0,0)$, right? But how to proof it is not asymptotic stability?

Comment: The trajectory conserves $V$, which will be nonzero if you didn't start at $(0,0)$, but $V((0,0))=0$.

Comment: I see! Thanks very much for your help!!!!